# how to generate a graph with asciidoc?

Tags: charts, svg, markdown

I was checking out this [asciidoc tutorial](http://asciidoctor.org/news/2014/02/18/plain-text-diagrams-in-asciidoctor/#controlling-the-output) and really liked the graph at `a,b,c,d` so i create such a file with that ascii text `1.ad` went ahead and installed [asciidoctor chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previe/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia?hl=en) but it just shows the plain text no graph, is there a way to plot the graph with this chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already a bit old, but it still deserves an answer :-)

In order to use graphs in asciidoc, you need a plugin. Asciidoctor Diagram is the one who solves the problem, but as far as I know, it is not available for the chrome extension. It also depends on graphviz isntalled on your machine.